# On average a Costguard station receives one distress call every two days. A "bad" week is a week in which 5 or more distress calls are received.

Tags: probability, combinations

(i) Find the probability that a week is a bad week.
(ii) Find the probability that, in 8 randomly chosen weeks, at least 2 are bad weeks.
(iii) Find the probability that, in 80 randomly chosen weeks, at least 30 are bad weeks.

I've figured the answer for (i), the probability that a week is a bad week:
1 call -> 7
2 calls -> C(7,2) = 21,
3 calls -> C(7,3) = 35,
4 calls -> C(7,4) = 35,
5 calls -> C(7,5) = 21,
6 calls -> C(7,6) = 7,
7 calls -> 1
**Probability= 29/127**

But I have no idea how to find (ii) and (iii). Also, does the fact that the station receives one distress call every two days on average affect the probability?

Comment: With part 1, you're making the assumption that there can only be one call a day.  What's the probability that there will be 8 calls? You're looking for the Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Hints...

For part a), use the Poisson distribution with $\lambda=3.5$

For part b), use the Binomial distribution with $n=8$ and $p=$ the answer to part a)

For part c) use the Binomial distribution with $n=80$ and $p$ as before, but use the Normal approximation with continuity correction to perform the calculation.